# Show custom error page after forcing logout in Liferay

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, logout, custom-error-pages

We have a requirement wherein I need to force logout user if some condition is met. I have written a `PostLoginAction` hook to check the condition and doing `getSession().invalidate()` when the condition is met. But after this, since there is no active session, Liferay takes me to login screen by default(prolly using a filter). If I try to redirect to one of the error pages inside `/ROOT/html/common/`, i get a cryptic *internal server error* page.

At this point, I need to display an error message but all the redirects are ending up on login page. What should be the right way of doing this?

Just on a side note, is there a way to display the error message on the login page itself instead of redirecting to some other page? I have tried using `sessionErrors.add()` method to achieve the same, but that too has not worked.

Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Do I get it right - you want to logout the user _immediately_ after the user was logged in? Could you add your current `PostLoginAction` to explain the problem better?

Comment: Did you try using creating a “login.events.pre” hook in liferay and invalidating user session in the action class?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke - my code is almost similar to what is given in the answer below.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal, i need to write a postlogin as I need to use user's OrganizationId to perform necessary checks. PreLogin action wont trigger liferay's auth mecahnism and I wont be able to get User object( and their OrganizationId ).

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps for achieving this

1. Create a post login event hook plugin
2. Create portal.properties with given props

   > login.events.post=com.liferay.sample.hook.LoginActionRedirect
3. Create entry in liferay-hook.xml

   portal.properties
4. Create class LoginActionRedirect

   ```
   package com.liferay.sample.hook;

   import java.io.IOException;

   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action;
   import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException;

   public class LoginActionRedirect extends Action {

   @Override
   public void run(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
           throws ActionException {
       System.out.println("Invalidating user");
       req.getSession().invalidate();
       try {
           //Use page URL to be redirected
           res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath()+"/web/guest/WCM");
       } catch (IOException e) {

           System.out.println("Something went wrong while performing IO operations");
       }
   }
   ```

   }
5. Add the following property to portal-ext.properties file,to avoid redirection with locale prepended

   > locale.prepend.friendly.url.style=0

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing, my question though is, whether putting a custom HTML under "/web/guest/WCM" and doing a sendReirect there is a valid/best way to handle the situation or not?

Comment: I m currently doing response.sendRedirect("/html/common/loginBreaker.html"); And I have placed that html under webapps/ROOT/html/common/ folder of liferay installation

Comment: @buch11 Using a web content on custom created page on portal is a better approach due to following reasons:1)No need to restart server in case of any content or page change 2)Changes can be easily deployed or pulled up from the server,directly using a hook.Please let me know for any further concerns.